# Enforce Model validations on test Fixtures AND/OR seed data as test data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest, test-fixture

I write auto-mated mini-test for my Rails app and sometimes it costs me an hour just to trace why my test failed while my manual test using Postman not. (Test vs Dev DB)

The problem turned out to be my test fixtures (YML) did not get validated and went straight to DB, while my seeded data in Dev DB, got validated and populated with attribute default values.

My questions are
1. How to Enforce Model validations on test Fixtures? Is it possible?
2. How to use seeds.rb to populate Test DB as well?

Thanks!